Sagemaker embedding return pydantic validation error
While trying to setup a SageMaker embedding using HuggingFace model, get_text_embedding return Pydantic error : Input should be a valid number.
May you have any idea ? Swapping models didn't change anything.
Running the HF embedding model on local (ollama) works fluently.
Related code :
hub = {
    'HF_MODEL_ID':'intfloat/e5-small-v2', # model_id from hf.co/models
    'HF_TASK':'feature-extraction', # NLP task you want to use for predictions
    'SAGEMAKER_MODEL_SERVER_TIMEOUT':'3600', 
    'TS_MAX_RESPONSE_SIZE':'2000000000',
    'TS_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE':'2000000000',
    'MMS_MAX_RESPONSE_SIZE':'2000000000',
    'MMS_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE':'2000000000',
}

# Configure the HF container
huggingface_model = HuggingFaceModel(
    env=hub, # configuration for loading model from Hub
    role=role, # iam role with permissions to create an Endpoint
    py_version='py310',
    transformers_version="4.37.0", # transformers version used
    pytorch_version="2.1.0",
    # pytorch version used
)

# Deploy HF embedding
embedding_predictor = huggingface_model.deploy(
    endpoint_name=name_from_base("bge-base-en-v15"),
    initial_instance_count=1,
    instance_type="ml.c6i.large"
)

# Declare embedding_model
embedding_model = SageMakerEmbedding(
    endpoint_name=embedding_predictor.endpoint_name,
    aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region_name=AWS_REGION
)

#Test embedding
embeddings = embedding_model.get_text_embedding("Test")

Return:
ValidationError: 1 validation error for EmbeddingEndEvent
embeddings.0.0
  Input should be a valid number [type=float_type, input_value=[[-0.5859060883522034, -0..., -0.27456873655319214]], input_type=list]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.8/v/float_type


Could you please add how you are importing HuggingFaceModel, SageMakerEmbedding classes in the code?
